# Python - Covert enum to Django models.CharField choices tuple

Tags: python, django, enums

I have this enum:

```
class Animal(Enum):
  DOG = 'dog'
  CAT = 'cat'
```

and in a Django model I have this:

```
possible_animals = (
  ("DOG", "dog"),
  ("cat", "cat"),
)
animal = models.CharField(choices=possible_animals, ...)
```

I know I can use the enum like this:

```
possible_animals = (
  (Animal.DOG.name, Animal.DOG.value),
  (Animal.CAT.name, Animal.CAT.value),
)
```

but is there any other elegant dynamic way to convert the enum into this kind of nested tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create enum class by inheriting the **`models.TextChoices`** as

```
class AnimalModel(models.Model):
    class Animal(models.TextChoices):
        DOG = 'dog'
        CAT = 'cat'

    animal = models.CharField(choices=Animal.choices)
```

Comment: thank you!
and it's act like an enum? meaning I can use it outside using: `Animal.DOG`?