# Enum values not enforced

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, I'm trying to create a enum-based database field. I'm avoiding external libraries and want to only use vanilla Django4.

Essentially, I'm replicating the example given in [Python - Covert enum to Django models.CharField choices tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869395/python-covert-enum-to-django-models-charfield-choices-tuple)

However, the enum values are not enforced. I can easily create a database entry with `animal = 'foo'` and it happily writes this into the database.

I am expecting this to yield an IntegrityError, since I'm explicitly using an enum so only valid values end up in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django indeed does not enforce enum values, or at least not out of the box. Strictly speaking that *could* be done: it passes the choices to the migration. But the migration system does not create specific types, or at least not by default.

You can however enforce these with a [**`CheckConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint):

```
from django.db.models import Q


class AnimalModel(models.Model):
    class Animal(models.TextChoices):
        DOG = 'dog'
        CAT = 'cat'

    animal = models.CharField(choices=Animal.choices)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(animal__in=list(Animal)), name='animal_valid'
            )
        ]
```

That being said, usually you process data through forms, serializers, etc. that will validate this. Usually just entering data through models is *not* a good idea: Django's models by default skip a lot of validation for performance reasons.